# PHP: echo heredoc from another script

Tags: php, while-loop, echo, heredoc

I am having trouble echoing out `heredoc` statements from one php file into another. I have one script which is used to retrieve API database information and then format that information into a `heredoc` to echo the information into the `index.php` page. The code that I have is:

```
while($artist_info = $artist_details_resource->fetch_assoc()){
   $artist = <<<DOC
             <img src="{$artist_info['image_url']}" alt="$artist_info['artist_name']" />
             <p>{$artist_name}</p>
DOC;
}
```

And in the index.php script I start a php clause on the place I want this heredoc to print. The code for that is:

```
<?php
  if($artist){
     echo $artist;
  }
?>
```

However this only prints the last heredoc string from the while loop, and not echoing out every heredoc through each iteration.

Comment: Did you try to print it from the same script?

Comment: yes even on the same script it prints only the last element

Comment: Isn't this herodoc missing ending DOC

Comment: your ending DOC is outside the codeblock by the way

Answer (score 2):

Why would it? You aren't echoing it in a loop, nor you are concatenating the string. You're overwriting the string on every iteration.

```
while($artist_info = $artist_details_resource->fetch_assoc()){
   $artist .= <<<DOC
             <img src="{$artist_info['image_url']}" alt="$artist_info['artist_name']" />
             <p>{$artist_name}</p>
}
```

Note the `.=`

Answer (score 1):

Of course this only prints the last string, because you use `$artist = <<<DOC` so you overwrite value of the $artist variable in every loop.

Try `$artist .= <<<DOC` or put it into array: `$artists[] = <<<DOC`